# думать or задуматься?

Tags: словоупотребление

What is the correct verb for this sentence:

> Она заставила себя закрыть глаза и **думать** о чём-нибудь приятном.

or:

> Она заставила себя закрыть глаза и **задуматься** о чём-нибудь приятном.

The idea is to close one's eyes and start thinking of something pleasant when one has trouble falling asleep. Are both or either of these possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"задуматься" is not quite the word here. It means "to think deeply about something", "to reflect on" (also, to be lost in thought: "он задумался и не заметил, как кончился обед").

I would use "думать" or perfective "подумать". "Думать" works here. Here it would be automatically interpreted as "made herself to *start* thinking about something good" (make oneself to "be thinking" doesn't sound good to me).

In the last part of the sentence you can also just say "... думать о приятном" or even "не думать о плохом" ("to not think about bad things").

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both are possible. However, **думать** is much better here in terms of modern colloquial Russian.

There are two actions - close (*закрыть*) and think (*думать*). Both words end with the suffix **ть**, so it will be correct to use one form of words (infinitive) in the sentence in this case.

If you use **задуматься**, it sounds like "She forced herself to close her eyes and think deeply about pleasant things".

Another example:

> Я заставлю себя сесть за стол и *делать* уроки

*Делать* means *do*.

> Я заставлю себя сесть за стол и *заняться* уроками

*Заняться* means *start doing something*. So it sounds like "I force myself to sit down and start doing homework".